# How much weight should a standard cabinet be able to support?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

I purchased standard cabinets (no plywood box) including a 33" farmhouse sink cabinet. I found a farmhouse sink I'd like to install and it's about 150lbs. (30" sink).

There is no weight rating on the cabinet I purchased, and the store I bought the cabinet from doesn't know how much weight it can hold.  Should I reinforce the cabinet? Or should it be able to hold the weight?

Comment: You also need to factor in how much water the sink will hold (1L of water = 1kg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend calling the cabinet manufacturer. They have almost assuredly done load tests to see how much weight their cabinets can carry before failing.

Comment: I emailed them and they told me to call the sink manufacturer for "installation instructions". Big help there...